# How to get Scheduled Local Notifications in react-native (ANDROID)

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am working on a react-native application where I need scheduled local notifications, So the user can receive push notifications at a specific time.

I have tried already react-native-push-notification and scheduled all my local notifications.

I want to get all my scheduled local notifications, on iOS i used this
PushNotificationIOS.getScheduledLocalNotifications, while on **Android** i couldn't find a way.

```
 PushNotificationIOS.getScheduledLocalNotifications(Localarray => {
        console.log("getScheduledLocalNotifications", Localarray);
  });
```

The above **ios** code part gets the local notifications that are currently scheduled in an array.

#### **Is there a way in android too ?**

Comment: If you are using expo, you can use `scheduleLocalNotificationAsync` https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/notifications/#notificationsschedulelocalnotificationasynclocalnotification-schedulingoptions

Comment: @sinan thank you for your reply but the thing is that I am not using expo

Answer (score 1):

```
PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications((nots)=>{
        console.log(nots);
})
```

Worked for me in my Android 8.0 device.

**Make sure to create some scheduled notification after calling this function.**

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't appear to be an easily accessible way to do it on Android. What I've done is, when I generate scheduled notifications, just store them in an array that I can access later. A bit redundant, but it's cross-platform.